# Загрузка курсора .cur для формы windows из ресурсов

Tags: c#

Как можно загрузить курсор прямо из ресурсов не выгружая его?

Есть пример ( выгружает курсор в папку Temp и загружает его от туда )

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);

public static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path)
{
        IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
        if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        }

        var curs = new Cursor(hCurs);
        var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(curs, true);
        return curs;
}

public static void DefaultCopy()
{
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Glows.cur"))
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Glows.cur", NameSpaceProject.Properties.Resources.Glows);
            }
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Загружаю курсор ( Form_Load )

```
 this.Cursor = LoadCustomCursor(Path.GetTempPath() + @"\Glows.cur");
```

Хотелось бы не выгружать его, а использовать напрямую из ресурсов.

Попробовал сделать так:

```
internal static Cursor InstallCursor()
{
   using (var oMS = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.NewCursor))
   {
       return new Cursor(oMS);
    }
}
Form_Load()
{
  Cursor = InstallCursor();
}
```

Курсор появился но без цвета ( черный цвет - кривой ).